# TypeError: BookList is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, django, function, django-templates, frontend

I have code js in my template in django app:

```
bookList = new BookList();
bookList.init();
updateBookUrlList();
```

And in this code I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: BookList is not a constructor`

I have this code in external file book-list.js:

```
var BookList=function(){};
BookList.prototype.init=function(){this.$eventslist=$(".event-list"),...
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

EDIT:

I changed my code to:

```
function BookList() {};
```

But now I get error: `TypeError: bookList.init is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Only change your function declaration from:

```
var BookList = function () {
```

To:

```
function BookList() {
```

When you assign a function to a variable, this can't be called before its declaration. But with the 2nd way, the function will be available from any part of your code, even before its declaration.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, can you check my edit now? @kevin-jimenez

Comment: Hi. The problem is that you're calling your `bookList` object before loading your external file.